# Installing Xamarin Error?

Tags: xamarin, installation

When I try to install Xamarin, after few minutes my installation failed. I got a notepad with this error::

The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

```
Incomplete workloads
    Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26403.0)

Incomplete components
    Android SDK setup (API level 23) (Component.Android.SDK23,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Google Android Emulator (API Level 23) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API23.V2,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) (Component.HAXM,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Java SE Development Kit (8.0.1120.15) (Component.JavaJDK,version=15.0.26403.0)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

Package 'JavaJDKV2,version=1.8.1,chip=x86' failed to download from 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=842899'.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=JavaJDKV2;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80131509
    Impacted workloads
        Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Impacted components
        Android SDK setup (API level 23) (Component.Android.SDK23,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Google Android Emulator (API Level 23) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API23.V2,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) (Component.HAXM,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Java SE Development Kit (8.0.1120.15) (Component.JavaJDK,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Details
        WebClient download failed: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
        Bits download failed: Error context: BG_ERROR_CONTEXT_REMOTE_FILE, Error code: -2145844844
        WinInet download failed: Url 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u112-b15/jdk-8u112-windows-i586.exe?AuthParam=1495491711_f7e41fbdd9ffae16fa075397d1b93914' returned HTTP status code: 404
```

Comment: An Oracle download link does not work. So you should try again, or talk to your network administrator to learn why.

Comment: It seems the Oracle URL(s) have changes